# Is this a secure way of producing random passwords?

Tags: php, security, passwords

Basically I have a script that allows members to register, passwords currently must contain at least 1 lower-case, 1 upper-case, 1 numeric and 1 special character, the password must also be at least 8 characters in length.

On the registration and password change pages I want to suggest 3 randomly generated strong passwords but not sure if my methods are the best way of doing it.

basically i run substr(str_shuffle()); against 4 set of characters, the first is lower case, the second is upper case, the third is numeric and the fourth is special characters.

Certain letters/numbers have been ommitted such as zero and O to avoid confusion between the 2. I have also repeated each character to allow for the option of each character to be included more than once.

I then do a final substr(str_shuffle()) on the output of the first 4 results to generate a password that is 10 characters in length and contains at least 2 of each of lower-case, upper-case, numeric and special characters.

```
// Generates a secure random password
$random_LC = substr(str_shuffle("abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyzabcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz"), 0, 2);
$random_UC = substr(str_shuffle("ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 2);
$random_NC = substr(str_shuffle("2345678923456789"), 0, 2);
$random_SC = substr(str_shuffle("@~#[]{}+&*%()£$\/<>@~#[]{}+&*%()£$\/<>"), 0, 4);

$random_PW = substr(str_shuffle("$random_LC$random_UC$random_NC$random_SC"), 0, 10);
$random_PW2 = substr(str_shuffle("$random_LC$random_UC$random_NC$random_SC"), 0, 10);
$random_PW3 = substr(str_shuffle("$random_LC$random_UC$random_NC$random_SC"), 0, 10);
```

The output could then be echoed through $random_PW, $random_PW2 etc.

A current example of what the above code outputs is

```
vH}[2p$W2&
5$/wM6q(\P
qM5w6/$\P(
$PM\/65w(q
```

I believe that if i simply did 1 substr(str_shuffle()) against all the characters there is a good chance that it would not meet the requirements of at least 1 of each character type being included in the output.

Is there an easier way to produce a random password that meets the above requirements?

Comment: Do you realize how much you have limited the passwordspace by that design? a passwordspace of 8 chars have more than 72^8=722204136308736 but by adding those limits you have 26*26*10*10(specials)*72^4=1816672665600 possible combinations. Pleas consider adding more characters.

Comment: These may be strong passwords from a maths point-of-view, but they're not from a usability point-of-view.  No-one is going to remember them!

Comment: let users choose their own password.

Comment: They do have the option of choosing their own passwords, these are displayed on the page as suggestions.

Comment: i would imagine not 1 in 100 would take your suggestion.

Comment: @user3340630 It’s actually 68^10 ≈ 2.11 × 10^18 in opposite to 23^2 × 24^2 × 8^2 × 13^2 × 12^2 ≈ 4.74 × 10^11.

Comment: Yes I was calculating 26 lowercase+26 uppercase + 10 numbers + 10 specials, but didn't double check that these were the exact numbers.

Comment: First, I'd recommend upping the length minimum.  Second, if these are just shown as suggestions, try adding [BubbleBabble](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-bubble-babble.htm) encoding as an option - at least then it's pronouncable, which may interest a few users.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth http://www.troyhunt.com/2011/03/only-secure-password-is-one-you-cant.html

Answer (score 1):

1. I'd suggest also varying the length of the password.
2. Probably it would be better not to have a constant number of special characters, lower case letters, uppercase and numbers. You could make sure that you have at least one of these and generate a random variation of mixed characters.

Here's an improved version (that generates a password between 8 and 12 characters and meets the criteria that you required):

```php
$chr = array_merge(
        range('A', 'N'), range('P', 'Z'),
        range('a', 'n'), range('p', 'z'),
        range(2, 9), str_split('@~#[]{}+&*%()£$\/<>')
       );

$password = $chr[mt_rand(0, 24)] . $chr[mt_rand(25, 49)]
          . $chr[mt_rand(50, 57)] . $chr[mt_rand(58, 76)];

for ($i = rand(4, 8); $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $password .= $chr[mt_rand(0, count($chr) - 1)];
}

$password = str_shuffle($password);
```

Comment: There's slight bug with this code. On refreshing a few times, it produced a single character `U` and other times a blank screen and other times a 3 character length `4Iy`.

Comment: If you run it in the browser, you are probably encountering the "<" character which hides the rest of the password.

Comment: I have seen it a few times, however even if this were the case, that should have still been seen. How do you explain the empty source on blank screen? (which happened 3x on 25 refreshes)

Comment: Here's a demo of the code above: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/545643fd9f276678fe8dd002f6255e5bb505cead (it works just fine)

Comment: [`mt_rand` may not be the best source of random values.](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2231)